# Watson Assistant preview link integration is not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm using IBM Watson Assistant and it's woking fine on "try it" simulation. But when I click on the preview link opens the screen below instead of my bot. What I am doing wrong?

"Connect to Agent
The connect to agent response type was received. In production, you would write code to handle this connection."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error on your side. When you create an assistent, you need to assign a dialog skill to that assistent. Thereafter, the preview link will work as expected.

You can create assistants independent of any skills. And you can assign multiple skills to an assistant. If there is no skill assigned to the assistant, that error is shown or - in a production system - handled by your error management.

Comment: I´ve created the skill but forgot to add to my assistant. It´s working now. Thank you very much!